# created two flavors dev,staging and called main function from them instead of main.dart.while building apk it is considering entry point as main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

`package:jansakti_dev/main.dart`
Error: No `main` method found.
Try adding a method named `main` to your program.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

I want to change it from `main.dart` to `main_dev.dart`

Comment: When u remove the void main() function & rewirte, then sometime this error happens . what u could do, open a new project & copy paste it, will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following

Create a file called `main_dev.dart` and it contains the following code

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And your `main.dart` contains

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
... your widget code
```

Now when you are trying to build apk form `main_dev.dart`
Run `flutter build apk --release -t lib/main_dev.dart`

You can create `main_dev.dart` and `main_prod.dart` or whatever flavours you want to add to your app and build apk from that flavours.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your file main_dev.dart

```
import 'main.dart' as runner;

 main() async {
 runner.main();
}
```

And run the app for ecample from vscode with this config:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "example dev debug",
        "request": "launch",
        "flutterMode": "debug",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main_dev.dart"
    }
 ]
}
```